# How to call SAP web service in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, saprfc

I have a RFC-enabled function in sap (`WebService`).. I want to call this function and get the result using `java`. What should I do? (I already have the `WSDL` endpoint)

Comment: You mean, you have generated a Web Service over an existing SAP RFC-enabled function module, and you want to call this Web Service from a java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it like consuming any other normal web service.

Use JAX-WS,which is the Java standard for it.

See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/) and [here](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-javaws/JAXWS3.html) for an example.You can also use HTTP clients to call the web service as well.[Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) is a great library if you want to go in that direction.There is an example available [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/) for that as well